# Performance comparision between Substring vs RegEx when start index is known

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to extract the first integer found in a `java.lang.String` and am unsure as to whether to try and use a `substring` approach or a regex approach:

```
// Want to extract the 510 into an int.
String extract = "PowerFactor510";

// Either:
int num = Integer.valueof(extract.substring(???));

// Or a regex solution, something like:
String regex = "\\d+";
Matcher matcher = new Matcher(regex);
int num = matcher.find(extract);
```

So I ask:

- Which type of solution is more appropriate here, and why?; and
- If the substring approach is more appropriate, what could I use to indicate the beginning of a number?
- Else, if the regex is the appropriate solution, what is the regex/pattern/matcher/method I should use to extract the number?

**Note:** The string will **always** begin with the word `PowerFactor` followed by a non-negative integer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regex would be more advisable due to faster processing.

Comment: Is regex really faster than `substring(11)`? The first part is always fixed... I don't think that parsing a regex, going through the string and extracting the appropriate group would be quicker than to just chop off the first 11 chars...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The string will always begin with the word "PowerFactor" followed by a
>   non-negative integer

This means you know exactly at which index you will find the number, i would say you better use the substring directly, at least considering the performance it would be much faster than searching and matching work.

```
extract.substring("PowerFactor".length());
```

I could not find any direct comparision but you can read about each one of the two options:

- [Java substring performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring)
- [Java Regex performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910514/java-regex-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Was a bit curious and tried the following

```
String extract = "PowerFactor510";
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(extract.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - l);

System.out.println();

l = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(extract.substring("PowerFactor".length()));
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - l);
```

And it tuned out that the second test was much faster, so `substring` wins.

Comment: Why in the world would you put `\D` in brackets there?

Comment: @tchrist Editted the answer

Comment: That is a horrible test. the replaceAll method of the String class performs an inline compile on the RegEx before processing it. The method does not yield a suitable test against Pattern/Matcher or anything RegEx related. Speed differences you are seeing are related to object creation and GC in the JVM.